# Publish data to RabbitMQ server via Mqtt

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I wrote a simple python program to connect `RabbitMqtt` server and hope to generate a queue and publish messages. However, after building the connection and creating a queue, the message was not published successfully (when I check the information of message, I cannot find any records and data). I wonder I miss some parameters or setting in  `client.publish()`, but I do not know how to figure it out.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe('SEEDQ')
    client.publish('SEEDQ', 'deqwdqwefqwefwefqwefqwe', 0, False)

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("15.78.xx.xx", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: So you are publishing to topic SEEDQ? You won't get a message on any topic unless you subscribe to the topic, did you do that?

Comment: Yes, I hope to publish to topic SEEDQ. Namely, should I change my code into:    client.subscribe('SEEDQ')  and client.publish('SEEDQ', 111, 0, False) ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, need to subscribe to receive messages,

Comment: It's probably unusual for one app to both publish and subscribe on the same topic, but as all subscribers on the topic will get copies of the message it won't disrupt anything.

Comment: I have changed to client.subscribe('SEEDQ') and client.publish('SEEDQ', 111, 0, False). But the RabbitMQ did not get message. I do not know why I can build the connection but cannot publish the message?

Comment: Can you edit/update into the question a minimal _complete_ code sample which shows the problem, so I can try it out?

Comment: Have you tried adding an on_publish callback function so you can confirm the publish succeeded?

Comment: I just ran the codes as I posted here, just importing the paho.mqtt.client and changing the '15.xx.xx.xx' to a real  address. I name the file as test.py and ran it on PyCharm. Then, I got the problem. If possible, could you help me try it on you side? Thanks

Comment: I did not use on_publish callback, because this is my first time to use mqtt. I only know subscribe and publish ... Sorry

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling client.publish() before the connection is complete. Move the client.publish into the on_connect function, AFTER client.subscribe('SEEDQ') and it will work.

```
# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
#    client.subscribe("$SYS/#")
    client.subscribe('SEEDQ')
    client.publish('SEEDQ', 111, 0, False)
```

Output:

```
Connected with result code 0
SEEDQ 111
```

FYI I used the public test server at iot.eclipse.org, port 1883.

FYI there is a very useful browser client [HERE](http://mqtt-helper.mybluemix.net/) -using this and the public test server messagesight.demos.ibm.com port 1883 you can subscribe to SEEDQ and see your python script publish, and also using the browser client you can publish to SEEDQ from your browser and your script will display the message while it is in the loop_forever(). Obviously using these test servers is public visible.

UPDATE here is the complete code - this works against the public servers I show above.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
#    client.subscribe("$SYS/#")
    client.subscribe('SEEDQ')
    client.publish('SEEDQ', 111, 0, False)


# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

#client.connect('15.xx.xx.xx', 1883, 60)
#client.connect("iot.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)
client.connect("messagesight.demos.ibm.com", 1883, 60)

#client.publish('SEEDQ', 111, 0, False)

# Blocking call that processes network traffic, dispatches callbacks and
# handles reconnecting.
# Other loop*() functions are available that give a threaded interface and a
# manual interface.
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: Thanks, I have moved the client.publish into the on_connect function, the RabbitMqtt still indicate there is no message. I post the codes as following.

Comment: You can and should edit your question to show your revised code rather than creating a new answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The second HERE link is Network Error.

Comment: Okay, I have revised codes in my question. I will delete the answer.

Comment: Updated the second HERE - I shouldn't have used a URL link anyway

Comment: I added the full code I used. This works against the public server - maybe there is something about RabbitMQ or your environment that is stopping the code working in your environment. Try it yourself on the public server.

Comment: BTW I'm running this code from the command prompt in Windows using Python 2.7. YMMV using different environments/OS/versions - can't help you with that

Comment: I also use Windows and Python 2.7. I guess the RabbitMQ is different from public sever. Anyway, I will check the RabbitMQ and hope to find the problem. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Just installed rabbitmq locally. Had to enable the rabbitmq mqtt plugin and restart the service and then the code above works fine against it. Maybe your broker has non-default settings for e.g. security/authentication that are stopping this simple example working.